# How to generate symbols for meta/command, option, shift and control on screen?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to show a list of keyboard shortcuts in my application showing what things like  "Shift-Right Arrow" and "command return" do in my application, but I can't find how to produce the symbols for these keys like the ones in say VS Code (shown below).

I thought I could find them in material icons but no luck there.  Is there an easy way to get these icons in my UI?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use unicode characters, you can find them [here](https://gist.github.com/Zenexer/c5243c4216f1f8cd2251)

Just copy and paste them into your HTML/TypeScript files